# Ajuda com Scroll Android

Tags: android, listview

Galera, tenho um botão flutuante na minha view que tira print de todos os itens que estão na minha listView. O que acontece é que quando clico no botão flutuante ele tira foto dos 3 primeiros itens e não tira do resto, mas no final atualiza a listView para os próximos itens. Parece que o código de tirar o print é mais rápido do que a atualização da listView.
Quando clico no botão flutuante a função screenShot é chamada.

@Override

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
        printScreen();
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
}

public void screenShot (){
    if (list.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        printScreen();
    } else {
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
}

public void printScreen(){
    int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
    int j = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = j; i < lastPosition; i++){
        if (list.getChildAt(i) != null && list.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) {
            JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(j), "operadora" + j + ".png");
        }
    }
    list.setSelection(lastPosition);
}
```

Comment: Essa linha `JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(j), "operadora" + j + ".png");` não é um bug? Não deveria ser `i` no lugar dos `j` ficando assim `JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(i), "operadora" + i + ".png");` ?

Comment: Sim, estava errado, mas também não resolveu o problema. Mas já arrumei, vou postar como ficou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei o código e ele ficou assim.

@Override

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (takingPictures && scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
        printScreen();
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
}

public void screenShot (){
    takingPictures = true;
    nextPicture = 0;
    if (list.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        printScreen();
    } else {
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
    }
}

public void printScreen(){
    int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
    int firstPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = nextPicture; i <= lastPosition; i++){
        if (list.getChildAt(i - firstPosition) != null && list.getChildAt(i - firstPosition).isEnabled()) {
            JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(i - firstPosition), "NomeArquivo" + i + ".png");
        }
    }
    nextPicture = lastPosition + 1;
    if (nextPicture == list.getCount()){
        takingPictures = false;
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "Imagens salvas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        int position = lastPosition + (lastPosition - firstPosition) + 1;
        if (position > list.getCount() - 1) {
            position = list.getCount() - 1;
        }
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    }
}
```